# Retrofit + Observable - Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, android, retrofit, observable

I'm trying to use New York Times API with Retrofit using Observable. But I'm getting this error when trying to use datas.

Can someone help me see where I'm wrong, please ?

Here is my ApiServices interface:

```
@GET("svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=HiddenApiKeyJustForThisMessage")
Observable<TopStoryResult> getTopStories();

@GET("svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=HiddenApiKeyJustForThisMessage")
Observable<List<NewsItem>> getResults();


Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.nytimes.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

Here is my ApiStreams class

```
public static Observable<TopStoryResult> streamFetchTopStories(){
    ApiServices mApiServices = ApiServices.retrofit.create(ApiServices.class);
    return mApiServices.getTopStories()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public static Observable<List<NewsItem>> streamFetchNews(){
    ApiServices mApiServices = ApiServices.retrofit.create(ApiServices.class);
    return mApiServices.getResults()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

And this is what I'm trying to do in my MainActivity. For now I just want to display in a TextView the list of each Title...

```
//------------------------
// Update UI
//------------------------
private void updateUIWhenStartingHttpRequest() {
    this.textView.setText("Downloading...");
}


private void updateUIWhenStopingHttpRequest(String response) {
    this.textView.setText(response);
}



//------------------------
// Rx Java
//------------------------
private void executeRequestWithRetrofit(){
    this.updateUIWhenStartingHttpRequest();

    this.disposable = ApiStreams.streamFetchNews()
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<NewsItem>>(){

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<NewsItem> topStories) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "On Next");
                    updateUIWithResult(topStories);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.e("TAG", "On Complete !");
                }
            });
}



private void updateUIWithResult(List<NewsItem> newsItemList){
    StringBuilder mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (NewsItem news : newsItemList){
        Log.e("TAG", "UPDATE UI" + news.getTitle());
        mStringBuilder.append("- " + news.getTitle() + "\n");
    }
    updateUIWhenStopingHttpRequest(mStringBuilder.toString());
}
```

[EDIT]
There are my two models for TopStories and NewsItem

TopStories:

```
private String status;
private String copyright;
private String section;
private String lastUpdated;
private Integer numResults;
private List<NewsItem> results = null;

public String getStatus() {return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getCopyright() {
    return copyright;
}

public void setCopyright(String copyright) {
    this.copyright = copyright;
}

public String getSection() {
    return section;
}

public void setSection(String section) {
    this.section = section;
}

public String getLastUpdated() {
    return lastUpdated;
}

public void setLastUpdated(String lastUpdated) {
    this.lastUpdated = lastUpdated;
}

public Integer getNumResults() {
    return numResults;
}

public void setNumResults(Integer numResults) {
    this.numResults = numResults;
}

public List<NewsItem> getResults() {
    return results;
}

public void setResults(List<NewsItem> results) {
    this.results = results;
}
```

NewsItem:

```
 private String section;
private String subsection;
private String title;
private String url;
private String byline;
private String updated_date;
private String created_date;
private String published_date;
private String material_type_facet;
private String kicker;


@SerializedName("abstract")
private String abstract_string;

private List<Multimedia> multimedia;


private transient String des_facet;
private transient String org_facet;
private transient String per_facet;
private transient String geo_facet;

public NewsItem() {
}

public NewsItem(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public NewsItem(String section, String subsection, String title, String url, String byline, String updated_date, String created_date, String published_date, String material_type_facet, String kicker) {
    this.section = section;
    this.subsection = subsection;
    this.title = title;
    this.url = url;
    this.byline = byline;
    this.updated_date = updated_date;
    this.created_date = created_date;
    this.published_date = published_date;
    this.material_type_facet = material_type_facet;
    this.kicker = kicker;
}

public String getSection() {
    return section;
}

public void setSection(String section) {
    this.section = section;
}

public String getSubsection() {
    return subsection;
}

public void setSubsection(String subsection) {
    this.subsection = subsection;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getByline() {
    return byline;
}

public void setByline(String byline) {
    this.byline = byline;
}

public String getUpdated_date() {
    return updated_date;
}

public void setUpdated_date(String updated_date) {
    this.updated_date = updated_date;
}

public String getCreated_date() {
    return created_date;
}

public void setCreated_date(String created_date) {
    this.created_date = created_date;
}

public String getPublished_date() {
    return published_date;
}

public void setPublished_date(String published_date) {
    this.published_date = published_date;
}

public String getMaterial_type_facet() {
    return material_type_facet;
}

public void setMaterial_type_facet(String material_type_facet) {
    this.material_type_facet = material_type_facet;
}

public String getKicker() {
    return kicker;
}

public void setKicker(String kicker) {
    this.kicker = kicker;
}


public String getAbstract() {
    return abstract_string;
}

public void setAbstract(String abstract_string) {
    this.abstract_string = abstract_string;
}

public List<Multimedia> getMultimedia() {
    return multimedia;
}

public void setMultimedia(List<Multimedia> multimedia) {
    this.multimedia = multimedia;
}

public String getDes_facet() {
    return des_facet;
}

public void setDes_facet(String des_facet) {
    this.des_facet = des_facet;
}

public String getOrg_facet() {
    return org_facet;
}

public void setOrg_facet(String org_facet) {
    this.org_facet = org_facet;
}

public String getPer_facet() {
    return per_facet;
}

public void setPer_facet(String per_facet) {
    this.per_facet = per_facet;
}

public String getGeo_facet() {
    return geo_facet;
}

public void setGeo_facet(String geo_facet) {
    this.geo_facet = geo_facet;
}
```

Here is what the JSON looks like:

[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aveKR.png)

First when I tried this one with Github user API, it works fine. But I can't figure out where I'm wrong there...

Is anybody can help me please ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you share your model too ? Because I suspect that the problem is the parsing your model into json.

Comment: your json returning Jsonobject and you are trying to catch as Json array using List as return type

Comment: @LesterL. Just edited my question with my two models

Answer (score 0):

Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT 
this means you are trying to a get a JSON Array as a List in JAVA but the api sent you a JSON OBJECT. So I cannot gather enough information but if I have to guess you should change this

```
@GET("svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=HiddenApiKeyJustForThisMessage")
Observable<List<NewsItem>> getResults();
```

to

```
@GET("svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=HiddenApiKeyJustForThisMessage")
Observable<NewsItemObject> getResults();
```

NewsItemObject is the Class that wraps NewsItem

Answer (score 0):

In your **ApiServices** interface you expect that `getResults()` returns `Observable<List<NewsItem>>`. Based on JSON you getting back this is not gonna work, because your root JSON element is **Object**, not an **Array**.

You have to create new wrapper Class (ResultsWrapper) with "results" field type of `List<NewsItem>`. Your method in ApiServices interface will then be:

```
@GET("svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=HiddenApiKeyJustForThisMessage")
Observable<ResultsWrapper> getResults();
```

That is what "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT" says to you.

Comment: I made a mistake when linked my NewsItem model, now it's the good one. Isn't it doing the wrapper job ?

Comment: @SebShad GsonConverter what you are using as an converter in your Retrofit instance is mapping Java List to JSON Array and vice versa. Other objects as for example mentioned ResultsWrapper or also your TopStoryResult are mapped to JSON Objects. Because your root JSON element is Object -> starting with "{", your Observable<List<NewsItem>> getResults(); cannot work, because GSON is trying to map LIST to JSON Array, but finding JSON Object. Is it understandable now?